Extensionality in probability
Trying to read this, I had problems making sense of this passage:

Henkin’s system is an intensional extension of Church’s system and is in that
respect an improvement on it, but it incorporates the problematic assumption of
extensionality, which says that the material equivalence of propositions (type t3) is
sufficient for their identity. Extensionality is problematic for a variety of reasons, most obviously in applications of the theory of probability. Suppose that a fair coin
is to be tossed, and let H and T be sentences that respectively formalize ‘the coin
lands heads’ and ‘the coin lands tails’. It would be normal to assume each of
1} Pr(H ∧ T) = 0,
2}   Pr(H) = 0.5,
3}   Pr(H ∨ T) = 1,


but this trio is simply inconsistent in an extensional system. The derivation of
a contradiction from the trio in an extensional system requires no extralogical
assumptions about probability function Pr or about anything else; the point is
that in an extensional system we can prove that there are only two propositions, so
no function can give them more than two values.

Can someone please explain the paradox found here? In what sense are there more than two values for Pr(H) and Pr(T)?
2} is straigthforward, Pr assigns the value 0.5 to H.
From 3} it follows by the addition rule that Pr(T) = 0.5.
And in 1} the events T and H are not independent of each other. So Pr(H ∧ T) = Pr(H) * Pr(T|H) = 0.5 * 0 = 0
Thanks!

In "extensional" system every proposition is materially equivalent to truth or falsehood. If material equivalence of propositions is sufficient for their identity then you cannot have Pr (or any other function of propositions) assign three or more values to them, like 0, 0.5 and 1. In your example, Pr(H ∨ T) cannot be 1 because H ∨ T is materially equivalent to either H or to H ∧ T, so Pr(H ∨ T) has to be 0.5 or 0. Thus, 1) - 3) is inconsistent.

If Pr is interpreted as a function over propositions -- so over truth-values, if an extensional interpretation is used -- you get into trouble. But it seems kind of silly to do this (and confusing to use it as example). Pr is usually defined as a function over sets. I guess that's then the point of the paragraph: The way subsets and propositions are linked up would be an intensional interpretation.

The problem is that in a purely extensional logic there are only two distinct propositions represented by true and false. The list you gave has three propositions: H ∧ T, H, and H ∨ T, so two of them have to be equal. A function like Pr can't assign two different values to the same proposition.
So, for example if the pair that are equal are H and H ∨ T, then Pr(H)=Pr(H ∨ T).
